# Call Swift APIs in Objective-C File

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In Swift, I extend the class "Date" to add one method named "swiftDate" used to print it self. May I use the method "swiftDate" like `[dateObject swiftDate]` in Objective-C environment？

Comment: Are you using `extension`?

Comment: Yes, i use the `extension`, but i do extend `Date` instead of `NSDate`.  `Date` is available above `iOS 10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I look up the [Apple Developer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date) and find that the `Date` is a `Class` declared in `Swift`, instead of `Objective-C`. So, I can not only use it in `Objective-C`, not to mention using the extended methods in `Swift`.

Maybe, I should extend its `ReferenceType`----`NSDate`. The classes that conform the protocol `ReferenceConvertible` have a typealias `ReferenceType`. For `Date`, its `ReferenceType` is `NSDate`.

You can look up the [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/referenceconvertible) to learn more about `ReferenceConvertible`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `import ProjectName-Swift.h` in Bridging header file then you can access swift method in your objective c class.

Comment: I know what you say. But, the point that I'd been emphasizing is the `Date` is a New class in `iOS 10` in Swift Foundation not in Objective-C, they are different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it.

Just Import swift class and initialise instance of swift class.
and call your method like

```
[swiftInstance swiftInstanceMethod];
```

Comment: I know what you say. But, the point that I'd been emphasizing is the `Date` is a New class in `iOS 10` in Swift Foundation not in Objective-C, they are different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ofcourse you can use it but you need to `import NSDate_SwiftDate.h` into bridging file `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` and also `import ProjectName-Swift.h` which is automatically generated when you create .h and .m file into swift project.

Comment: I know what you say. But, the point that I'd been emphasizing is the `Date` is a New class in `iOS 10` in Swift Foundation not in Objective-C, they are different classes.